# How to use `.to_string` method of `pd.DataFrame` to return string with actual `\t` characters?

Tags: python, string, pandas, format, output

I want to recreate the `matrix` string with the `.to_string` method of `pd.DataFrame`.

**I can't figure out how to use the built in `.to_string` method to achieve a format that contains the `\t` characters matching the input format?**

Can this be done or do I need to create a custom parser?

```
matrix = """
#Names\tcol1\tcol2\tcol3\tcol4\tcol5\tcol6\tcol7
A\t-1.23\t-0.81\t1.79\t0.78\t-0.42\t-0.69\t0.58
B\t-1.76\t-0.94\t1.16\t0.36\t0.41\t-0.35\t1.12
C\t-2.19\t0.13\t0.65\t-0.51\t0.52\t1.04\t0.36
D\t-1.22\t-0.98\t0.79\t-0.76\t-0.29\t1.54\t0.93
E\t-1.47\t-0.83\t0.85\t0.07\t-0.81\t1.53\t0.65
F\t-1.04\t-1.11\t0.87\t-0.14\t-0.80\t1.74\t0.48
G\t-1.57\t-1.17\t1.29\t0.23\t-0.20\t1.17\t0.26
H\t-1.53\t-1.25\t0.59\t-0.30\t0.32\t1.41\t0.77
"""

df = pd.read_table(StringIO(matrix), index_col=0)
df.to_string()
# '        col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7\n#Names                                          \nA      -1.23 -0.81  1.79  0.78 -0.42 -0.69  0.58\nB      -1.76 -0.94  1.16  0.36  0.41 -0.35  1.12\nC      -2.19  0.13  0.65 -0.51  0.52  1.04  0.36\nD      -1.22 -0.98  0.79 -0.76 -0.29  1.54  0.93\nE      -1.47 -0.83  0.85  0.07 -0.81  1.53  0.65\nF      -1.04 -1.11  0.87 -0.14 -0.80  1.74  0.48\nG      -1.57 -1.17  1.29  0.23 -0.20  1.17  0.26\nH      -1.53 -1.25  0.59 -0.30  0.32  1.41  0.77'

pd.__version__
'0.22.0'
```

Comment: Would something like `df.to_csv(None, sep='\t')` work or are you specifically looking for something that uses `to_string`?

Comment: Woah... I had no idea `None` brings a string back.  That is actually really cool.  If no one has a `to_string` solution then I will accept this as an answer. `df.to_csv(None, sep="\t", index_label="#Names")` ended up working